# How to have django model utils Choices handle lowercase and uppercase

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

How can i use uppercase characters when adding a property with lowercase choices

this is the payload im using Clover is capitalized but i want to know how i can have capitalized and lowercase Clover work at the same time using model_utils Choices

```
           "name": "Test",
           "pos_name": "Clover",
```

```
class Tenant(TimeStampedModel):
    POS = Choices('square', 'clover', 'omnivore')


    pos_name = models.CharField(choices=POS, max_length=50, blank=True, default='')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe by overriding model's __setattr__?

```
def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
    if attr == "pos_name":
        value = value.lower()
    super().__setattr__(attr, value)
```